# Need to fix simple layout error

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am new to android and I am using the Big Nerd Ranch Guide to learn (chapter 3 now). In the photo below, I want to put the buttons at bottom corners. But, they are both at the top left. How do I fix it ? XML code also given after photo. I solved the problem by removing the previous and next buttons out of their horizontal layout view. But, can i still have it in that layout and have both displayed at the bottom ?

[image]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="24dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/true_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/false_button" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/previous_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:text="@string/previous_button"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:drawablePadding="12dp" 
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:text="@string/next_button" 
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp" 
        />

    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the buttons layout to [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) so its easy to manage relative position.

Note the properties I set for it to work:

```
alignParentLeft="true"
alignParentRight="true"
```

---

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="24dp" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/true_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/true_button" />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/false_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/false_button" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/previous_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/previous_button"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_left"
                android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/next_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/next_button"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
                android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                />

    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. that works. I wonder which is a better way - relative layout or just make the button go left/right like I did.